# jQuery Mobile popup open/close is not firing until end of function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I have a jQuery Mobile (jQM) Single Page Application (SPA).  I am trying to display a popup during what may be a long-running process.  The popup open/close doesn't work until the cleanUp function terminates.  As such, I get a brief flash of the popup at that time, so that at least is working. The larger application is also working but not this specific cleanUp function.

I have tried including a popup() initialization before the open.  I have also tried using setTimeout wrappers around each popup. Though I am using Sprockets to build the app, I manually migrated the cleanUp code into the main body after the pagecreate. I have been unable to have the popup fire on open and then close upon close.

This app is very complex so I have tried to extract the jQM app in question for this question.  Since it is an SPA, the HTML file contains several logical pages within it.  Each cleanUp popup is included immediately following the div with data-role="main".  The popup in question is included, with the same HTML ID, on each logical page and therefore is included multiple times in one physical HTML page.  jQM is intended to appropriately manage this issue as jQM's processing actually requires it since it maintains copies both the old and the new logical pages within one physical page to support page transitions.

This is the jQM extraction.  The HTML can be inferred from this code, too.

```
let triggered;
const oneMinute = 60 * 1000;
const oneSecond = 1000;

$(function ($, window, document) {

    $("body").pagecontainer({
        defaults: false
    });
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on("pagecreate", "#pageone", function (event, ui) {

            function delay(seconds) {
                for (let count = 0; count < seconds; count++) {
                    let _currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                    while (_currentTime + oneSecond >= new Date().getTime()) {
                    }
                }
            }

            let cleanUpTimer;

            function setCleanUpTimer(seconds) {
                return cleanUpTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    cleanUp();
                }, seconds * oneSecond)
            }

            function clearCleanUpTimer(timer) {
                return clearTimeout(timer)
            }

            function cleanUp() {
                clearCleanUpTimer(cleanUpTimer);
                let _page = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage')[0].id;
                if (_page !== "") {
                    // id=cleanUpMessage is included in each jQm 'div <data-role=page...>', which means several/many are included within the HTML page.
                    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').find("#cleanUpMessage").popup("open");
                    console.log("Clean up fired.");
                    delay(10);
                    // Problem: #cleanUpMessage doesn't display until the following command && doesn't clear until after function return
                    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').find("#cleanUpMessage").popup("close");
                    console.log("Clean up ended.");
                }
                setCleanUpTimer(10);
                return false;
            }

            // pagecreate fires on every page change, even AJAX changes

            // This stabilizer prevents disruption of the jQM environment on changes
            if (triggered === undefined) {
                triggered = true;

                cleanUp();

            } // stabilzer end
        }
    ) // pagecreate end

}(window.jQuery, window, document)); // function end
```

The popup is _cleanup.html:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="cleanUpMessage">
  <p>Please wait while clean up is in process.
</div>
```

A sample of a logical page would be this, where _cleanup.html contains the popup as frontend/cleanup.html"

```
<div data-theme="a" data-role="page" id="anchor_page">
  <%= partial :'frontend/header.html', locals: {page: 'Anchor Page'} %>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <%= partial :'frontend/cleanup.html' %>
    <p>This is the last page.
  </div>
  <%= partial :'main-footer.html' %>
</div>
```

Note: This is a Ruby/Sinatra/Rack Middleware/WebSockets application.  The partials are supported using the Sinatra-Partial gem.

Update: Modified cleanUp to attempt to use afteropen.  In this case, neither the popup nor the callback fired.

```
    function cleanUp() {
        clearCleanUpTimer(cleanUpTimer);
        let _page = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage')[0].id;
        if (_page !== "") {
            // id=cleanUpMessage is included in each jQm 'div <data-role=page...>', which means several/many are included within the HTML page.
            $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').find("#cleanUpMessage").popup({
                afteropen: function (event, ui) {
                    console.log("Clean up fired.");
                    delay(10);
                    // Problem: #cleanUpMessage doesn't display until the following command && doesn't clear until after function return
                    //$(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer('getActivePage').find("#cleanUpMessage").popup("close");
                    console.log("Clean up ended.");
                }
            });
        }
        setCleanUpTimer(10);
    }
```

Comment: (1) A popup won't appear if you open it on `pagecreate`, especially with heavy pages. Even `setTimeout` wouldn't work properly. Wait until `pagecontainershow` is triggered; you can add `setTimeout` inside that event just in case. (2) popup shouldn't be included within other divs, it should be a direct child of page div. (3) I would recommend using an external popup. It can be accessed from any page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd, but after a few (dozen) permutations, I found one that works.  The problem that I had was that I could not seem to fire the popup and clear it in the same function. I start the cleanUp function in cleanUpStart and then spin off cleanUpProcess using setTimeout.  It's kind of messy but it works...

```
const oneMinute = 60 * 1000;
const oneSecond = 1000;
const pound = "#";

$(function ($, window, document) {

    $("body").pagecontainer({
        defaults: false
    });
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on("pagecreate", "#pageone", function (event, ui) {

            function delay(seconds) {
                let _currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                let _delay = seconds * oneSecond;
                while (_currentTime + _delay >= new Date().getTime()) {
                }
            }

            let cleanUpStartTimer;
            let cleanUpProcessTimer;

            function setCleanUpStartTimer(seconds) {
                return cleanUpStartTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    cleanUpStart();
                }, seconds * oneSecond)
            }

            function clearCleanUpStartTimer(timer) {
                return clearTimeout(timer)
            }

            function cleanUpProcess() {
                console.log("Clean Up Processing");
                // Clean up process here;
                delay(3);
                console.log("Clean Up Processed");
            }

            function runCleanUpProcess(seconds, _page) {
                return cleanUpProcessTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    if (_page !== "") {
                        cleanUpProcess();
                        $(document).one("pagechange", function (event) {
                            $("#cleanUpMessage").popup("close");
                            console.log("Clean Up Ended.");
                        });
                        $(document).pagecontainer("change", pound + _page);
                    }
                    setCleanUpStartTimer(10);
                }, seconds * oneSecond)
            }

            function cleanUpStart() {
                clearCleanUpStartTimer(cleanUpStartTimer);
                let _page = $("body").pagecontainer('getActivePage')[0].id;
                if (_page !== "") {
                    $(document).one("pagechange", function (event) {
                        $("#cleanUpMessage").popup("open");
                        console.log("Clean Up Fired.");
                    });
                    $(document).pagecontainer("change", pound + _page);
                }
                runCleanUpProcess(1, _page);
                return false;
            }

            if (theGlobals.triggered === undefined) {
                theGlobals.triggered = true;

                cleanUpStart();

            } // stabilzer end
        }
    ) // pagecreate end

}(window.jQuery, window, document)); // function end
```

Comment: For whomever voted this down, if you have a better answer I'd  sure like to see it.  Thanks.

Comment: Trying to replicate your issue yesterday i was able to open and close the `popup` during the `pagecreate` event - but you answered yourself already. So, this isn't a downvote against you nor your work, but i find your sentence *firing the popup and clearing it does not really work in the same function* not correct.

Comment: @deblocker I would really appreciate seeing your working code!  I tried so many different ways to make it work.  I do not like my solution.  Please, if you would, post yours.  I'd be very happy to accept a better answer!  Thanks.  (Also, please mention the jQuery/jQM version you are using.  My jQM is 1.4.5 and jQuery is 2.1.4, both  pulled from Google.

Comment: Honestly, i can't say if what i did is really what you need, but i had a similar problem in the past with a heavy task while trying to display a progress-bar. IMHO - as you already discovered - the key point is your tight loop between `popup.open`and `popup.close`. Here, using `setTimeout(1) ` - at least  `(1)`  - is mandatory. So, you are right - by strictly speaking - that this isn't executed during the same `pagecreate` trigger but, in fact, the code is positioned inside the same function. Sorry for the pedantry. At the end, i used the `afteropen` event.

Comment: I believe you could put the rest of the page initialization inside `beforeshow`. Will rewrite & post asap the working code. It is far simpler than yours, so i can't really say if it will fulfill all your complex requirements, but the concept should work.

Comment: @deblocker  I edited the statement to say that I had the problem, not that it was not possible.